# Need help on retrieving JSON attributes from a flow file in Apache NiFi

Tags: json, apache-nifi

I'm trying to get the attribute values from a JSON file using EvaluvateJsonPath processer in NiFi.

Below is the sample JSON file

```
{"widget": {
    "debug": "on",
    "window": {
        "title": "Sample Konfabulator Widget",
        "name": "main_window",
        "width": 500,
        "height": 500
    },
    "image": { 
        "src": "Images/Sun.png",
        "name": "sun1",
        "hOffset": 250,
        "vOffset": 250,
        "alignment": "center"
    },
    "text": {
        "data": "Click Here",
        "size": 36,
        "style": "bold",
        "name": "text1",
        "hOffset": 250,
        "vOffset": 100,
        "alignment": "center",
        "onMouseUp": "sun1.opacity = (sun1.opacity / 100) * 90;"
    }
}}
```

Below is my configuration.

[image: Configuration]

The expected output should be "main_window". But i'm getting the whole JSON string as the output. Can someone please point me in the right direction, what went wrong here?

Update:

This is the flow file content, i'm seeing in the queue as an outcome of EvaluvateJsonPath processer.

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have given `"Name"-->$.widget.window.name` correctly.

But you have to specify `"ReturnType"-->json` not to be `"ReturnType"-->autodetect`.

That's the problem for you have received whole json string.

**EDIT-1**

If you change return type to be json then you can receive your expected output **"main_window"` to be stored in Attribute ${Name}**.

After that you can use **ReplaceText** processor to Specify replacement value **"${Name}"** then you can receive **"main_window"** in flowfile

It could be worked for me.

And Let me know if you face any issues

Comment: I've tried the other options ( i.e Scalar & Json) yet i'm getting the full string as output. Any other problem ?

Comment: you have mean output is flow file or attribute value?

Comment: flow file. I'm seeing the output in the queue.

Comment: ok but your question says you have try to get that "Main_window" to be store in that attribute.Now i have edited my answer for only receive "Main_window" in flowfile.Check my EDIT-1